# Failed building the Rust documentation: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: rust

I'm on Windows, trying to build the Rust documentation.

I cloned the Rust repository, copied the `config.toml.example` under the name `config.toml` and executed `./x.py doc` but here is the error I get (with the `RUST_BACKTRACE` environment variable set to `full`):

```sh
~\source\repos\rust [master ≡]> ./x.py doc
~\source\repos\rust [master ≡]> Updating only changed submodules
Submodules updated in 0.08 seconds
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.41s
thread 'main' panicked at 'fs::read_dir(builder.src.join(&relative_path).join("redirects")) failed with The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)', src\bootstrap\doc.rs:243:21
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x7ff7a88e481f - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::dbghelp::trace
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\..\..\backtrace\src\backtrace\dbghelp.rs:98
   1:     0x7ff7a88e481f - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\..\..\backtrace\src\backtrace\mod.rs:66
   2:     0x7ff7a88e481f - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:67
   3:     0x7ff7a88e481f - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::{{impl}}::fmt
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:46
   4:     0x7ff7a89029da - core::fmt::write
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\core\src\fmt\mod.rs:1110
   5:     0x7ff7a88df148 - std::io::Write::write_fmt<std::sys::windows::stdio::Stderr>
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\io\mod.rs:1588
   6:     0x7ff7a88e8356 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:49
   7:     0x7ff7a88e8356 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:36
   8:     0x7ff7a88e8356 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:208
   9:     0x7ff7a88e7e39 - std::panicking::default_hook
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:225
  10:     0x7ff7a88e89b5 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:622
  11:     0x7ff7a88e85a1 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:519
  12:     0x7ff7a88e513f - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace<closure-0,!>
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:141
  13:     0x7ff7a88e84f9 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:515
  14:     0x7ff7a890ad7c - std::panicking::begin_panic_fmt
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:457
  15:     0x7ff7a8166b14 - bootstrap::doc::{{impl}}::run
                               at C:\Users\jerome\source\repos\rust\src\bootstrap\doc.rs:243
  16:     0x7ff7a8349024 - bootstrap::builder::Builder::ensure<bootstrap::doc::TheBook>
                               at C:\Users\jerome\source\repos\rust\src\bootstrap\builder.rs:1563
  17:     0x7ff7a81661a0 - bootstrap::doc::{{impl}}::make_run
                               at C:\Users\jerome\source\repos\rust\src\bootstrap\doc.rs:200
  18:     0x7ff7a80eff44 - bootstrap::builder::StepDescription::maybe_run
                               at C:\Users\jerome\source\repos\rust\src\bootstrap\builder.rs:181
  19:     0x7ff7a80f0402 - bootstrap::builder::StepDescription::run
                               at C:\Users\jerome\source\repos\rust\src\bootstrap\builder.rs:202
  20:     0x7ff7a80f42b9 - bootstrap::builder::Builder::run_step_descriptions
                               at C:\Users\jerome\source\repos\rust\src\bootstrap\builder.rs:610
  21:     0x7ff7a80f3f7d - bootstrap::builder::Builder::execute_cli
                               at C:\Users\jerome\source\repos\rust\src\bootstrap\builder.rs:590
  22:     0x7ff7a7f25950 - bootstrap::Build::build
                               at C:\Users\jerome\source\repos\rust\src\bootstrap\lib.rs:620
  23:     0x7ff7a7f11773 - bootstrap::main
                               at C:\Users\jerome\source\repos\rust\src\bootstrap\bin\main.rs:33
  24:     0x7ff7a7f127eb - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<fn(),tuple<>>
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:227
  25:     0x7ff7a7f126db - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace<fn(),tuple<>>
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:125
  26:     0x7ff7a7f11101 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}<tuple<>>
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\library\std\src\rt.rs:49
  27:     0x7ff7a88e8f0a - core::ops::function::impls::{{impl}}::call_once
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:280
  28:     0x7ff7a88e8f0a - std::panicking::try::do_call
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:401
  29:     0x7ff7a88e8f0a - std::panicking::try
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:365
  30:     0x7ff7a88e8f0a - std::panic::catch_unwind
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\panic.rs:434
  31:     0x7ff7a88e8f0a - std::rt::lang_start_internal
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\/library\std\src\rt.rs:34
  32:     0x7ff7a7f110df - std::rt::lang_start<tuple<>>
                               at /rustc/bf62f4de32a085c1080d9e77b1b73f1a8e42cce2\library\std\src\rt.rs:48
  33:     0x7ff7a7f11d66 - main
  34:     0x7ff7a8909ac4 - invoke_main
                               at D:\agent\_work\9\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
  35:     0x7ff7a8909ac4 - __scrt_common_main_seh
                               at D:\agent\_work\9\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
  36:     0x7fff5ee37034 - BaseThreadInitThunk
  37:     0x7fff5f302651 - RtlUserThreadStart
Build completed unsuccessfully in 0:00:02
```

I tried under Ubuntu with WSL but I get the same error.

I tried Googling this error but found nothing and the [Rust Readme](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust#building-documentation) is saying nothing special except the command I ran

Could you please tell me what am I missing and how to build the documentation?
I'd like to end up with Markdown files so I can read the book on my phone while being offline.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: What do you get when you run `ls src/doc/book/`? It seems like the submodule for the Rust book wasn't checked out properly.

Comment: @Smitop this directory was empty. As I wrote in my answer down bellow, using the `stable` branch instead of the `master` one solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the remote branches and saw a `stable` branch which I checked out.
I tried running again the command `./x.py doc` and this time it worked well.

I saw they don't have any `develop` branch and all the Pull Requests on Github have the `master` as target branch. So it seems their `master` branch is what I usually call the `develop` branch at my work.

As of today the `master` branch seems a bit broken since building the documentation doesn't work but using the `stable` branch worked like a charm.